# Pill on empty stomach timing?

Tags: dogs

When the instructions say “on an empty stomach” for giving a pill, how long before/after pill time is required?
And, does empty mean literally no food or is it okay to wrap pill in small piece of cold cut turkey? Shoving a pill in my dogs mouth isn’t pleasant.

Comment: I would give my vet a call and ask them these questions. They know the medication and why they prescribed it.

Answer (score 3):

If a medication needs to be given on an empty stomach, my general advice is to give at least 2 hours after feeding, and 2 hours before the next meal.

The stomach is probably not *completely* empty for a number of hours longer than this, but the poor dog needs his breakfast at some point. Stomach emptying times can vary based on a particular dog, other medical conditions, etc., but normal gastric emptying time in dogs is about 2-6 hours.

The reason some medications may be best given on an empty stomach is that food may affect the drug absorption.

Giving the pill wrapped in a small piece of turkey is unlikely to have any major impact on the drug in most cases. However, if you are concerned then it would be best to contact your veterinarian for advice in your dog's specific case. You could also post the name of the medication here if you would like advice about the particular medication.